# J1.5 - How to add image button into joomla article

Tags: joomla, imagebutton, article

I am trying to add the images as button into existing article of web page. When I click on that button it have to redirect into another page or Url.

I have searched on net. I didn't get satisfied response.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743561/add-custom-button-to-joomlas-article-editor-tinymce) page too.

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have added the button using **edit code** option in joomla article, by inserting the following html code.

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="link_to_be_opened_on_image_click" class="weblink" style="text-decoration:none">
<img border="0" src="source_of_the_image_button.png" alt="Title" title="Title" />
</a>
```