# I wish to add a button on the admin dashboard in Joomla 3.5, where in code do I need to make changes?

Tags: joomla, namespaces

This button would be 'share' and placed at the article editor just like we have buttons like 'save','edit' etc
I facing a problem understanding joomla code structure and which file I need to make changes so as to add this button. Should it be administrator/layout/editor/ ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a free plugin that can help you share your contents in social network. have a look http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/social-web/social-comments/social-comments-and-sharing-for-joomla .

Also there are several other plugins that may suit your requirements then to hack the core files [http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=share+button](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension?searchall=share%20button&filter[tags][]=&filter[core_catid]=&filter[includes]=&filter[versions]=&filter[type]=&filter[hasdemo]=&order=&filter[newupdated]=&filter[score]=&filter[favourites]=&dir=DESC&limitstart=0&controller=filter&view=extension&layout=list&Itemid=145&clearorders=0&clearfilters=1)

if you want to develop your custom editor button then you can check this link
[Add Custom Button to Joomla's Article Editor (TinyMCE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743561/add-custom-button-to-joomlas-article-editor-tinymce)